# Android - Character Encoding with Ant Release

Tags: android, character-encoding

In my app I write out a list of hard coded string values, from the class in a List as below:

```
getSalePricesMin().put(40000, "£40,000"); getSalePricesMin().put(60000, "£60,000"); 
getSalePricesMin().put(80000, "£80,000"); getSalePricesMin().put(100000, "£100,000"); 
getSalePricesMin().put(120000, "£120,000"); getSalePricesMin().put(180000, "£180,000");
```

They are displayed In a standard spinner.
When I build the App using Eclipse, the '£' symbols display correctly, however, I need to release using ant, and when I do this I get the bad encoding as shown below.

[image]

I have tried adding java.encoding=UTF-8 to the ant.properties file, but this does not change.

Any advise? Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Replacing £ symbols for \u00a3 worked a treat.

```
getSalePricesMin().put(40000, "\u00a340,000");
getSalePricesMin().put(60000, "\u00a360,000");
getSalePricesMin().put(80000, "\u00a380,000");
getSalePricesMin().put(100000, "\u00a3100,000");
getSalePricesMin().put(120000, "\u00a3120,000");
```